# using Beanstalkd on IronMQ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, beanstalkd, ironmq

I am migrating beanstalkd server to ironmq

it's said here in 
http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/beanstalk/#authentication

> Authentication
>
> Because IronMQ requires authentication, the first command you send
>   must put a message onto the queue with the contents:
>
> oauth {TOKEN} {PROJECT_ID}
>
> The DRAINING response will be returned if authentication fails or if
>   any other command is sent before authentication.

but how exacly to do that?
i already try to use

```
Backburner::Worker.enqueue SomeJobs, "oauth {TOKEN} {PROJECT_ID}"
```

and

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
     -H "Authorization: OAuth {TOKEN}" 
     -d '{"messages":[{"oauth":"{TOKEN} {PROJECT_ID}"}]}' 
     "https://mq-aws-us-east-1.iron.io/1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/queues/my_queue/messages"
```

but still failed (got DRAINING response when queueing real message)
please help

fyi i am using Backburner as Beanstalkd client on RoR

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend not using the beanstalk interface for IronMQ, the next gen version of IronMQ will not support it so it's probably best to use the HTTP interface regardless. It's really easy to use with the IronMQ Ruby gem so it shouldn't be too difficult to switch: https://github.com/iron-io/iron_mq_ruby